# Deployment project for WPF app - How do I stop the application before install?

Tags: wpf, deployment

I want to configure the installer to stop a WPF application if it is running before installing the new version.

How do I do this in a Setup & Deployment Project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short of communicating with the app with some other little app that runs before the installation takes place (which would be way overkill), I don't know that you could do this automatically, but the installer should prompt the user to shut it down. Does it not?

Comment: Nope, the installer removes all the files but the exe is still running (shows in the Task Manager). Eventually the application crashes when a background task runs. So far I've got a vbscript that kills the process and the installer calls the script before continuing. Ideally I wanted something a bit more graceful but I guess this will have to do for now.